# what's wrong with this RegExp? ( The preceding token is not quantifiable)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will:

1) capture a group immediately preceded by 'Seite' and followed by one or more spaces (but no text other than spaces), which will be referenced as \1

2) be immediately followed by this group (i.e. \1) **but not include it a second time**

A valid example would be:

input: `Seite120 kljwqenflkjqwef 120`
output: `120 kljwqenflkjqwef`

I'm not sure how to make this work.  My best try is:

```
((?<=Seite)(?=\s)).*(?=\1)
```

Can anyone better than me at RegExp take a stab at it?

Comment: There cannot be any match in the string you shared as there are no 1+ spaces after `Seite`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  When I plug that into https://regex101.com/ it gives me the same error that mine is getting :/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I'm trying to match a group in the first capture that has 1+ spaces after what is captured, i.e. 120

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I see, thanks.  I actually didn't want to include the final 120, even though I accidentally wrote it in my example to begin with.

Comment: I am not sure now what you need at all. See [this update](https://regex101.com/r/aXjABj/2). At any rate, capturing a zero-width assertion will only result in an empty string inside the group buffer, it makes no sense.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Your update almost got it.  Sorry for being unclear.  I want to include the first captured group in the beginning but leave it out at the end.  The first captured group should be used with a positive lookahead at the end that's not included.  The valid output is listed in my edited question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capturing a zero-width assertion will only result in an empty string inside the group buffer.

You may use

```
Seite\K(\S+)\s+\S.*?(?=\s*\1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Aj3eYm/1)

**Details**:

- `Seite` - a substring `Seite`
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `(\S+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ non-whitespace symbols
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\S` - a non-whitespace
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the first
- `(?=\s*\1)` - 0+ whitespaces followed with the contents of Group 1 (as this pattern is part of the lookahead, the text matched with this construct is not added to the match value).

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation.  Do you happen to know how I could get this to work in Javascript?

Comment: Easy. Just use capturing groups, see a [JS fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dqewqwvk/). There are other ways, too.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you indicate you are writing the regex for JavaScript. Therefore, to answer your initial question about why you are receiving the error "The preceding token is not quantifiable" it is because you are using a look behind assertion `(?<=Seite)` and look behind assertions are not supported in JavaScript. The `?<=` portion of your regex can't be interpreted by the JavaScript regex engine.